# Angular 2 build without CLI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I followed the docs in their site on how to build an angular 2 app, but the problem is all the `.js` files are still living in the same directory of the `.ts` file which will be very problematic if my app grows or have many .ts files. How can make sure after compilation it will be put in the `dist` directory without using angular cli? Because it tried angular cli, it is very slow. It will take a minute just to reflect a simple changes in my file.

How can i use like this directory structure:

- dist

  - index.html
  - myapp-component.js
  - another.js
    -- etc...
- src

  - index.html
  - myapp.component.ts
  - another.ts
    -- etc...

and/or if it is possible to minify or make does js file into 1 big .js file only.

Also to put angular js source files/dependencies in the dist/library folder not from `node_modules`.